# Javascript, cant capture button click

Tags: javascript, templates, html-framework-7

This template is on friends page init. I have tried to call button click in 2 ways button#id  or just with #id but i havent been able to capture the button click. I have debugged it and it never joins onClick function. I would appreciate any help or documentation link. Thanks for your time.

```
<script class="friend-list" type="text/template7">
    <div class="friendsamigos">
      <ul>
        {{#each this}}
          <li><a>{{this.displayName}}</a><button id="getfriendprofile" class="col button button-fill button-little" data="{{this.uid}}" >"Go"</button></li>             
        {{/each}}
      </ul> 
    </div>   
  </script>

$$(document).on('page:init', '.page[data-name="friends"]', function(e){
    console.log("Friends page loaded");
    postMyFriends();
    $$('#back-home-button').on('click', function(e){
        view.router.navigate('/home/')
    })
    $$('#getfriendprofile').on('click', function(e){
        var friendUID = $$(this).data();
        console.log(friendUID);
        console.log($$(this).data());
        //requestFriendProfile(friendUID);
    })
```

Comment: Do You assigned $$ with Dom7 like in docs?

Comment: Robert - Yes, ofc. i have made many pages and everything works.The back button on this page, works too. Just the getprofileone im not able to capture it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The problem was I was loading the onclick function at page init. While template wasnt loaded yet. I did something like this :

```
 <script class="friend-list" type="text/template7">
    <div class="friendsamigos" id="id-list-amigos">
      <ul>
        {{#each this}}
          <li><a>{{this.displayName}}</a><button class="friendProfileButton col button button-fill button-little" data-uid={{this.uid}} >"Go"</button></li>             
        {{/each}}
      </ul> 
    </div>   
  </script>
```

And loaded the onclick function after the template load:

```
function postMyFriends(){
    var localStorageUserData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myuser'));
    var uid = localStorageUserData.uid;
    app.request.post(serverurl + 'postMyFriends', {user : uid}, onSuccess, onError)

    function onSuccess(data, status){
        if( status === 200){

         TemplatesWorkInRequest('.friend-list', '#friendsamigos', data )

        }
        $$('.friendProfileButton').on('click', function(e) {
            var friendUID = $$(this).data('uid');
            console.log(friendUID);
           // requestFriendProfile(friendUID);
        });

    }
    function onError(err){
        console.log(`Something went wrong ${err}`)
    }

}
```

I dont think it needs but here is the template function:

```
function TemplatesWorkInRequest(templateToCompile, insertPathSelector, data){
    var template = $$(templateToCompile).html();
    var compiletTemplate = Template7.compile(template);

    var dataToJSON = JSON.parse(data)
    var html = compiletTemplate(dataToJSON);
    $$(insertPathSelector).html(html);

}
```

Thank you all for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

Use $ instead of $$ in your code like this:

```
$(document).on('page:init', '.page[data-name="friends"]', function(e){
    console.log("Friends page loaded");
    postMyFriends();
    $('#back-home-button').on('click', function(e){
        view.router.navigate('/home/')
    })
    $('#getfriendprofile').on('click', function(e){
        var friendUID = $(this).data();
        console.log(friendUID);
        console.log($(this).data());
        //requestFriendProfile(friendUID);
    })
```

Comment: I use the Dom7 library instead of jquery thats why the $$, anyway i tried but still dont work. Thanks for your time